# Global variabless in Python

Tags: python

How can I create variables that all the methods in the class will share (fields or global vars)?

Another question: what is the meaning of ";" in python?

Comment: do instances share it or it's different for each instance?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function-other-than-the-one-that-created-them

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide more detail to get more meaningful answers.

There are several ways to make a variable available to the methods of a class;

**Instance variable:** defined in the scope of the current class *instance*. Commonly created with `__init__()`, i.e. when the instance is initiated.

```
class SomeClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.greeting = 'Hello'
    def greet(self, name):
        return self.greeting + name
```

**Class variable:** defined in the class definition. Shared between instances

```
class SomeClass(object):
    greeting = 'Hello'
    def greet(self, name):
        return self.greeting + name
```

Note that self.greeting references the *class* variable `greeting` via the *instance*. Assigning to `self.greeting` does **not** change the class variable but rather overwrites the `greeting` instance attribute with the new value. A more explicit, perhaps clearer way of accessing the class variable is `self.__class__.greeting`

**Module (global) variable:** defined in the top-level, usually the module.

Define the variable *outside* the class definition and reference it within your class functions.

```
greeting = 'Hello'

class SomeClass(object):
    def greet(self, name):
        return greeting + name
```

There are all sorts of reasons why this is not often a good idea. Search Stackoverflow for 'python globals' and you'll find many explanations about why, as well as cases where it might be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Answering "Another question"

';' (semicolon) is a statement separator.
The [Python Grammar](http://docs.python.org/reference/grammar.html) defines a `simple_stmt` as

```
simple_stmt: small_stmt (';' small_stmt)* [';'] NEWLINE
```

A trivial example:

```
>>> a=1; b=2; c=3
>>> a,b,c
(1, 2, 3)
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you define a variable outside of any function or class, it is available to all the functions and classes within that file. For example:

```
message="Hello, world"
def speak():
    print message
```

By default, these variables are read-only. You can't modify `message` from within `speak` unless you specifically mark that variable as global:

```
message="Hello, world"
def speak():
    global message
    message = "hello, python!"
    print message
```

As for  your other question, semicolon is a statement separator:

```
message="Hello, world" ; print message
```

It is rarely used, as there's rarely ever a compelling reason to put two statements on a single line.

In the above, the global instance of `message` will be changed after `speak()` is called.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe like this.

```
class A:
    x = 0
    def inc(self):
        self.__class__.x += 1

b = A()
b.inc()  # A.x == 1, b.x == 1
c = A()  
c.inc()  # A.x == 2, c.x == 2
```

`;` is logic line wrap for python, it is not recommended, as it make code difficult to read.

Comment: waaaay too complicated for such a simple question.

Comment: @BryanOakley So what's your defination of `complicated`?

Comment: @lostyzd. not sure what bryan means by "complicated", but your code is certainly an uncommon way of writing a class method. in more recent versions of python (>=2.4), this would be done with a classmethod decorator.

Comment: @ekhumoro Thanks, I know howto write a classmethod by `@staticmethod`, I didn't mean to write a class method, this could be used in `__init__`.

Comment: @lostyzd. `@classmethod` is not the same as `@staticmethod`. with a classmethod, the class is passed as first argument, so you could have written `cls.x += 1`. (with a staticmethod, neither the class nor the instance is passed as first argument).

Comment: @lostyzd: what's my definition of complicated? In the context of this question and answer, anything that involves the use of advanced features such as `__class__`. This is a newbie trying to learn a very basic concept.